# opencv- contourArea doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, canny-operator

I followed [this opencv guide](https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/20/sorting-contours-using-python-and-opencv/) to sort the contours in the first image by size.

I calculated an edge map (the result is the middle image):

```
# load the image and initialize the accumulated edge image
image = cv2.imread("legos.png")
accumEdged = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
# loop over the blue, green, and red channels, respectively
for chan in cv2.split(image):
    # blur the channel, extract edges from it, and accumulate the set
    # of edges for the image
    chan = cv2.medianBlur(chan, 11)
    edged = cv2.Canny(chan, 50, 200)
    accumEdged = cv2.bitwise_or(accumEdged, edged)
# show the accumulated edge map
cv2.imwrite("images/Edge_Map.png", accumEdged)
```

then I calculated and drawn some contours from it:

```
def draw_contour(image, c, color):
    # compute the center of the contour area
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    # draw the countour and its area on the image
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, color, 2)
    cv2.putText(image, str(cv2.contourArea(c)), (cX - 10, cY - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.65, color,2)

# find contours in the accumulated image
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

sorted_cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

draw_contour(image, sorted_cnts[0], (0, 0, 0))  # forth brick
draw_contour(image, sorted_cnts[4], (80, 0, 80))  # small circle
draw_contour(image, sorted_cnts[6], (255, 255, 255))  # third brick
```

the problem is that the contours are not sorted (the way I thought). I included the first, fifth and seventh contours along with their areas. The fifth (area 229) is clearly smaller than the seventh (area 130).

I would like to know what cv2.contourArea does in this case.

[image: initial image]
[image: edged image]
[image: final image]

Comment: Why are you using Canny?  You should just threshold on saturation from HSV. The colors will be high saturation and the background will be low saturation. That will get you cleaner contours of the blocks without the extra streamers that add to your areas. Your areas do not look reasonable. All blocks are nearly the same size but you 130 and 229 marked for the top green block and 172225.5 for the bottom block. That is much too different.

Comment: The function is fine, it's the input contour that's garbage. Fix that.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue i dropped contourArea and wrote this function. using the The Shoelace formula we can find the area of contour.

```
def polygon_area(coords):
    n = len(coords)  
    area = 0
    for i in range(n):
        j = (i + 1) % n
        area += coords[i][0] * coords[j][1]
        area -= coords[j][0] * coords[i][1]
    area = abs(area) / 2.0
    return area
```

For example we can consider a triangle with vertices (1, 1), (2, 3), (4, 1):

```
vertices = [(1, 1), (2, 3), (4, 1)]
area = polygon_area(vertices)
print(area)
```

Output :

```
3.0
```

Just a note be sure that the co-ordinates you are passing to it is for a closed polygon.

Comment: The problem with this is that sometimes (like in this case) the contours are not a closed polygon. Is there another way?

Comment: It would be useful to future readers if you added links to formulae/techniques you are using, e.g. **Shoelace Formula** at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula#:~:text=The%20shoelace%20formula%2C%20also%20known,Cartesian%20coordinates%20in%20the%20plane.